# Understanding results of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I just started learning about Gram-Schmidt, and I understand what it does, but I'm having trouble showing *why* it works.

For example, let $P_k$ for $k=1,...,p$ be a projection matrix for a matrix $A_{1:k}$ (so the first $k$ columns). Then let's say we have $u_1 = a_1$, and any $u_k = (I-P_{k-1})a_k$ for each $k$. How do I:

1) Show that the $u_k$ are orthogonal

2) Show that the span of $u_1,...,u_k$ is the same as the span of $a_1,...,a_k$ for each $k=1,...,p$.

I feel a bit dumb because I realize that both these results are the the whole point of Gram-Schmidt. #2 I thought should be especially obvious but when I tried to prove it I got no where fast. I was trying to take advantage of the fact that $P$ is symmetric/idempotent, but maybe that's not the approach to take? Can anyone help? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V_k = [\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k\}]$ be the linear span of the first $k$ basis elements, and let $P_k$ be the orthogonal projection of the full space $V$ onto the subspace $V_k$. The dimension of $V_k$ is $k$. By definition of $P_k$, the vector $P_kx$ is the unique vector for which
$$
           P_kx \in V_k,\;\;\;(x - P_k x)\perp V_{k-1}.
$$
(Special handling is required for $k=1$ of course.)
Therefore $v_k = a_k-P_{k-1}a_k$ is in $V_k$ and $v_k \perp V_{k-1}$, which gives
$$
                   v_k \perp v_{j},\;\;\; j=1,2,\cdots,k-1.
$$
None of the $v_k$ can be $0$ because $v_k =a_k-P_{k-1}a_k\notin V_{k-1}$. So $\{ v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\}$ is a set of non-zero mutually orthogonal vectors whose span is contained in $V_k$, which means that $\{ v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\}$ is a basis of $V_k$, because of dimension.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I think I see what you did. Its hard for me to picture these things geometrically sometimes, but I think your solution is clever. I suppose I was too concerned with taking advantage of algebraic properties, and just ignored the definition for too long. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnAlperto : Orthogonal projection came up in Calculus, because, given a point $x$ and a plane $\mathcal{P}$ or a line, the closest point $y\in\mathcal{P}$ to $x$ is such that the vector for $x$ to $y$ is orthogonal to the plane or the line. The vector from the point to its projection points orthogonally out of the plane or line. Same idea here in an arbitrary inner product space. Turns out that closest point projection and orthogonal projection onto  a subspace are the same, regardless of dimension: one exists iff the other exists and, if either exists, the two are the same.